# How to find version of an application installed using c#

Tags: c#, windows, installation, windows-installer

How to find version of an application installed, using c#. Is there a way to know component id of application?

EDIT: I need to get version of an already installed application.This is required for generating the diagnostics report on users machine.

Example:Version of Outlook 2007 installed on a user's machine

Comment: Do you want the version of the currently running application or another application which is out of your program?

Comment: yes, please look at the EDIT in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo("some.dll");
```

Comment: This approach we have find the dll(s) copied by application installer/update to application and find the version of dll.

Answer (score 2):

If it's assemblies you're after:

For the current assembly:

`Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version`

Replace Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly() with an Assembly instance you got through other means to determine that one's version.

One way would be:

> Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("something.dll");

It will return the value from the AssemblyVersion attribute.

Answer (score 0):

There is no unified method suitable for all the applications I'm afraid. But for MS office application you may get version via COM objects.

Sorry, I don't have outlook on my computer, so I can't try it with oulook. But with excel and word it can be done like that:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
Console.WriteLine("Excel: Version-" + excelApp.Version + " Build-" + excelApp.Build);
Console.WriteLine("Word: Version-" + wordApp.Version + " Build-" + wordApp.Build);
```

I think that getting version of other MS applications will be quite the same.
Good luck.

PS. Do not forget to call **Quit()** in the end and to release com objects via **Marshal.ReleaseComObject()** method like

```
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excelApp);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wordApp);
```